# How do I keep the items in the top right of my navbar in place when I zoom in or out?

Tags: html, css, navbar

[PHOTO OF THE WEBSITE WITH NORMAL ZOOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmDFR.png) So I'm trying to keep the Login and svg in the top right corner when zooming in or out, for those two things I use the nav_end class. Also when I zoom in i just zoom into the top left corner of the website, instead i want to keep  seeing the full navbar with the center in the middle, the logo in the top left and the login  in the top right. I've seen some other posts covering this but they dont use flex boxes so I didnt really know how to adapt that to my own code.

Here's the code (note: I put global.css in style.css):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/WebTechJ1/header_footoer/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/WebTechJ1/global.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav_bar flex--row">
        <div class="navbar_center flex--row ">
            <div class="nav_logo flex--row">
                <svg width="106" height="31" viewBox="0 0 106 31" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M12.875 18.0469C12.875 17.6406 12.8125 17.276 12.6875 16.9531C12.5729 16.6198 12.3542 16.3177 12.0312 16.0469C11.7083 15.7656 11.2552 15.4896 10.6719 15.2188C10.0885 14.9479 9.33333 14.6667 8.40625 14.375C7.375 14.0417 6.39583 13.6667 5.46875 13.25C4.55208 12.8333 3.73958 12.349 3.03125 11.7969C2.33333 11.2344 1.78125 10.5833 1.375 9.84375C0.979167 9.10417 0.78125 8.24479 0.78125 7.26562C0.78125 6.31771 0.989583 5.45833 1.40625 4.6875C1.82292 3.90625 2.40625 3.23958 3.15625 2.6875C3.90625 2.125 4.79167 1.69271 5.8125 1.39062C6.84375 1.08854 7.97396 0.9375 9.20312 0.9375C10.8802 0.9375 12.3438 1.23958 13.5938 1.84375C14.8438 2.44792 15.8125 3.27604 16.5 4.32812C17.1979 5.38021 17.5469 6.58333 17.5469 7.9375H12.8906C12.8906 7.27083 12.75 6.6875 12.4688 6.1875C12.1979 5.67708 11.7812 5.27604 11.2188 4.98438C10.6667 4.69271 9.96875 4.54688 9.125 4.54688C8.3125 4.54688 7.63542 4.67188 7.09375 4.92188C6.55208 5.16146 6.14583 5.48958 5.875 5.90625C5.60417 6.3125 5.46875 6.77083 5.46875 7.28125C5.46875 7.66667 5.5625 8.01562 5.75 8.32812C5.94792 8.64062 6.23958 8.93229 6.625 9.20312C7.01042 9.47396 7.48438 9.72917 8.04688 9.96875C8.60938 10.2083 9.26042 10.4427 10 10.6719C11.2396 11.0469 12.3281 11.4688 13.2656 11.9375C14.2135 12.4062 15.0052 12.9323 15.6406 13.5156C16.276 14.099 16.7552 14.7604 17.0781 15.5C17.401 16.2396 17.5625 17.0781 17.5625 18.0156C17.5625 19.0052 17.3698 19.8906 16.9844 20.6719C16.599 21.4531 16.0417 22.1146 15.3125 22.6562C14.5833 23.1979 13.7135 23.6094 12.7031 23.8906C11.6927 24.1719 10.5625 24.3125 9.3125 24.3125C8.1875 24.3125 7.07812 24.1667 5.98438 23.875C4.89062 23.5729 3.89583 23.1198 3 22.5156C2.11458 21.9115 1.40625 21.1406 0.875 20.2031C0.34375 19.2656 0.078125 18.1562 0.078125 16.875H4.78125C4.78125 17.5833 4.89062 18.1823 5.10938 18.6719C5.32812 19.1615 5.63542 19.5573 6.03125 19.8594C6.4375 20.1615 6.91667 20.3802 7.46875 20.5156C8.03125 20.651 8.64583 20.7188 9.3125 20.7188C10.125 20.7188 10.7917 20.6042 11.3125 20.375C11.8438 20.1458 12.2344 19.8281 12.4844 19.4219C12.7448 19.0156 12.875 18.5573 12.875 18.0469ZM26.2488 10.3438V30.5H21.7488V7.09375H25.9206L26.2488 10.3438ZM36.9519 15.3594V15.6875C36.9519 16.9167 36.806 18.0573 36.5144 19.1094C36.2331 20.1615 35.8165 21.0781 35.2644 21.8594C34.7123 22.6302 34.0248 23.2344 33.2019 23.6719C32.3894 24.099 31.4519 24.3125 30.3894 24.3125C29.3581 24.3125 28.4623 24.1042 27.7019 23.6875C26.9415 23.2708 26.3008 22.6875 25.78 21.9375C25.2696 21.1771 24.8581 20.2969 24.5456 19.2969C24.2331 18.2969 23.9935 17.224 23.8269 16.0781V15.2188C23.9935 13.9896 24.2331 12.8646 24.5456 11.8438C24.8581 10.8125 25.2696 9.92188 25.78 9.17188C26.3008 8.41146 26.9363 7.82292 27.6863 7.40625C28.4467 6.98958 29.3373 6.78125 30.3581 6.78125C31.431 6.78125 32.3738 6.98438 33.1863 7.39062C34.0092 7.79688 34.6967 8.38021 35.2488 9.14062C35.8113 9.90104 36.2331 10.8073 36.5144 11.8594C36.806 12.9115 36.9519 14.0781 36.9519 15.3594ZM32.4363 15.6875V15.3594C32.4363 14.6406 32.3738 13.9792 32.2488 13.375C32.1342 12.7604 31.9467 12.224 31.6863 11.7656C31.4363 11.3073 31.1029 10.9531 30.6863 10.7031C30.28 10.4427 29.7852 10.3125 29.2019 10.3125C28.5873 10.3125 28.0613 10.4115 27.6238 10.6094C27.1967 10.8073 26.8477 11.0938 26.5769 11.4688C26.306 11.8438 26.1029 12.2917 25.9675 12.8125C25.8321 13.3333 25.7488 13.9219 25.7175 14.5781V16.75C25.7696 17.5208 25.9154 18.2135 26.155 18.8281C26.3946 19.4323 26.7644 19.9115 27.2644 20.2656C27.7644 20.6198 28.4206 20.7969 29.2331 20.7969C29.8269 20.7969 30.3269 20.6667 30.7331 20.4062C31.1394 20.1354 31.4675 19.7656 31.7175 19.2969C31.9779 18.8281 32.1602 18.2865 32.2644 17.6719C32.379 17.0573 32.4363 16.3958 32.4363 15.6875ZM45.7788 7.09375V24H41.2631V7.09375H45.7788ZM40.9819 2.6875C40.9819 2.03125 41.211 1.48958 41.6694 1.0625C42.1277 0.635417 42.7423 0.421875 43.5131 0.421875C44.2735 0.421875 44.8829 0.635417 45.3413 1.0625C45.81 1.48958 46.0444 2.03125 46.0444 2.6875C46.0444 3.34375 45.81 3.88542 45.3413 4.3125C44.8829 4.73958 44.2735 4.95312 43.5131 4.95312C42.7423 4.95312 42.1277 4.73958 41.6694 4.3125C41.211 3.88542 40.9819 3.34375 40.9819 2.6875ZM57.7619 20.7969C58.314 20.7969 58.8035 20.6927 59.2306 20.4844C59.6577 20.2656 59.991 19.9635 60.2306 19.5781C60.4806 19.1823 60.6108 18.7188 60.6213 18.1875H64.8556C64.8452 19.375 64.5275 20.4323 63.9025 21.3594C63.2775 22.276 62.439 23 61.3869 23.5312C60.3348 24.0521 59.1577 24.3125 57.8556 24.3125C56.5431 24.3125 55.3973 24.0938 54.4181 23.6562C53.4494 23.2188 52.6421 22.6146 51.9963 21.8438C51.3504 21.0625 50.866 20.1562 50.5431 19.125C50.2202 18.0833 50.0588 16.9688 50.0588 15.7812V15.3281C50.0588 14.1302 50.2202 13.0156 50.5431 11.9844C50.866 10.9427 51.3504 10.0365 51.9963 9.26562C52.6421 8.48438 53.4494 7.875 54.4181 7.4375C55.3869 7 56.5223 6.78125 57.8244 6.78125C59.2098 6.78125 60.4233 7.04688 61.465 7.57812C62.5171 8.10938 63.34 8.86979 63.9338 9.85938C64.5379 10.8385 64.8452 12 64.8556 13.3438H60.6213C60.6108 12.7812 60.491 12.2708 60.2619 11.8125C60.0431 11.3542 59.7202 10.9896 59.2931 10.7188C58.8765 10.4375 58.3608 10.2969 57.7463 10.2969C57.09 10.2969 56.5535 10.4375 56.1369 10.7188C55.7202 10.9896 55.3973 11.3646 55.1681 11.8438C54.939 12.3125 54.7775 12.849 54.6838 13.4531C54.6004 14.0469 54.5588 14.6719 54.5588 15.3281V15.7812C54.5588 16.4375 54.6004 17.0677 54.6838 17.6719C54.7671 18.276 54.9233 18.8125 55.1525 19.2812C55.3921 19.75 55.7202 20.1198 56.1369 20.3906C56.5535 20.6615 57.0952 20.7969 57.7619 20.7969ZM76.5263 24.3125C75.2138 24.3125 74.0367 24.1042 72.995 23.6875C71.9533 23.2604 71.0679 22.6719 70.3388 21.9219C69.62 21.1719 69.0679 20.3021 68.6825 19.3125C68.2971 18.3125 68.1044 17.25 68.1044 16.125V15.5C68.1044 14.2188 68.2867 13.0469 68.6513 11.9844C69.0158 10.9219 69.5367 10 70.2138 9.21875C70.9013 8.4375 71.7346 7.83854 72.7138 7.42188C73.6929 6.99479 74.7971 6.78125 76.0263 6.78125C77.2242 6.78125 78.2867 6.97917 79.2138 7.375C80.1408 7.77083 80.9169 8.33333 81.5419 9.0625C82.1773 9.79167 82.6565 10.6667 82.9794 11.6875C83.3023 12.6979 83.4638 13.8229 83.4638 15.0625V16.9375H70.0263V13.9375H79.0419V13.5938C79.0419 12.9688 78.9273 12.4115 78.6981 11.9219C78.4794 11.4219 78.146 11.026 77.6981 10.7344C77.2502 10.4427 76.6773 10.2969 75.9794 10.2969C75.3856 10.2969 74.8752 10.4271 74.4481 10.6875C74.021 10.9479 73.6721 11.3125 73.4013 11.7812C73.1408 12.25 72.9429 12.8021 72.8075 13.4375C72.6825 14.0625 72.62 14.75 72.62 15.5V16.125C72.62 16.8021 72.7138 17.4271 72.9013 18C73.0992 18.5729 73.3752 19.0677 73.7294 19.4844C74.094 19.901 74.5315 20.224 75.0419 20.4531C75.5627 20.6823 76.1513 20.7969 76.8075 20.7969C77.62 20.7969 78.3752 20.6406 79.0731 20.3281C79.7815 20.0052 80.3908 19.5208 80.9013 18.875L83.0888 21.25C82.7346 21.7604 82.2502 22.25 81.6356 22.7188C81.0315 23.1875 80.3023 23.5729 79.4481 23.875C78.594 24.1667 77.62 24.3125 76.5263 24.3125Z" fill="black"/>
                    <path d="M91.4469 1.25L95.7281 9.1875L100.009 1.25H105.369L98.7594 12.5312L105.541 24H100.134L95.7281 15.9062L91.3219 24H85.8844L92.6813 12.5312L86.0563 1.25H91.4469Z" fill="#4E8341"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_middle flex--row">
                <p>Home</p>
                <p>About us</p>
                <p>History</p>
                <p>Saved</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_end flex--row">
                <p>Naam</p>
                <svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M25.2513 26.625C25.1055 26.6042 24.918 26.6042 24.7513 26.625C21.0846 26.5 18.168 23.5 18.168 19.8125C18.168 16.0416 21.2096 12.9791 25.0013 12.9791C28.7721 12.9791 31.8346 16.0416 31.8346 19.8125C31.8138 23.5 28.918 26.5 25.2513 26.625Z" stroke="#5C5C5C" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M39.0414 40.3752C35.3331 43.7711 30.4164 45.8336 24.9997 45.8336C19.583 45.8336 14.6663 43.7711 10.958 40.3752C11.1663 38.4169 12.4163 36.5002 14.6455 35.0002C20.3538 31.2086 29.6872 31.2086 35.3539 35.0002C37.5831 36.5002 38.8331 38.4169 39.0414 40.3752Z" stroke="#5C5C5C" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M24.9998 45.8333C36.5057 45.8333 45.8332 36.5058 45.8332 25C45.8332 13.494 36.5057 4.16663 24.9998 4.16663C13.4939 4.16663 4.1665 13.494 4.1665 25C4.1665 36.5058 13.4939 45.8333 24.9998 45.8333Z" stroke="#5C5C5C" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                </svg>
                    
            </div>
     </div>  
    </div>

</body>
</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/WebTechJ1/header_footoer/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/WebTechJ1/global.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav_bar flex--row">
        <div class="navbar_center flex--row ">
            <div class="nav_logo flex--row">
                <svg width="106" height="31" viewBox="0 0 106 31" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M12.875 18.0469C12.875 17.6406 12.8125 17.276 12.6875 16.9531C12.5729 16.6198 12.3542 16.3177 12.0312 16.0469C11.7083 15.7656 11.2552 15.4896 10.6719 15.2188C10.0885 14.9479 9.33333 14.6667 8.40625 14.375C7.375 14.0417 6.39583 13.6667 5.46875 13.25C4.55208 12.8333 3.73958 12.349 3.03125 11.7969C2.33333 11.2344 1.78125 10.5833 1.375 9.84375C0.979167 9.10417 0.78125 8.24479 0.78125 7.26562C0.78125 6.31771 0.989583 5.45833 1.40625 4.6875C1.82292 3.90625 2.40625 3.23958 3.15625 2.6875C3.90625 2.125 4.79167 1.69271 5.8125 1.39062C6.84375 1.08854 7.97396 0.9375 9.20312 0.9375C10.8802 0.9375 12.3438 1.23958 13.5938 1.84375C14.8438 2.44792 15.8125 3.27604 16.5 4.32812C17.1979 5.38021 17.5469 6.58333 17.5469 7.9375H12.8906C12.8906 7.27083 12.75 6.6875 12.4688 6.1875C12.1979 5.67708 11.7812 5.27604 11.2188 4.98438C10.6667 4.69271 9.96875 4.54688 9.125 4.54688C8.3125 4.54688 7.63542 4.67188 7.09375 4.92188C6.55208 5.16146 6.14583 5.48958 5.875 5.90625C5.60417 6.3125 5.46875 6.77083 5.46875 7.28125C5.46875 7.66667 5.5625 8.01562 5.75 8.32812C5.94792 8.64062 6.23958 8.93229 6.625 9.20312C7.01042 9.47396 7.48438 9.72917 8.04688 9.96875C8.60938 10.2083 9.26042 10.4427 10 10.6719C11.2396 11.0469 12.3281 11.4688 13.2656 11.9375C14.2135 12.4062 15.0052 12.9323 15.6406 13.5156C16.276 14.099 16.7552 14.7604 17.0781 15.5C17.401 16.2396 17.5625 17.0781 17.5625 18.0156C17.5625 19.0052 17.3698 19.8906 16.9844 20.6719C16.599 21.4531 16.0417 22.1146 15.3125 22.6562C14.5833 23.1979 13.7135 23.6094 12.7031 23.8906C11.6927 24.1719 10.5625 24.3125 9.3125 24.3125C8.1875 24.3125 7.07812 24.1667 5.98438 23.875C4.89062 23.5729 3.89583 23.1198 3 22.5156C2.11458 21.9115 1.40625 21.1406 0.875 20.2031C0.34375 19.2656 0.078125 18.1562 0.078125 16.875H4.78125C4.78125 17.5833 4.89062 18.1823 5.10938 18.6719C5.32812 19.1615 5.63542 19.5573 6.03125 19.8594C6.4375 20.1615 6.91667 20.3802 7.46875 20.5156C8.03125 20.651 8.64583 20.7188 9.3125 20.7188C10.125 20.7188 10.7917 20.6042 11.3125 20.375C11.8438 20.1458 12.2344 19.8281 12.4844 19.4219C12.7448 19.0156 12.875 18.5573 12.875 18.0469ZM26.2488 10.3438V30.5H21.7488V7.09375H25.9206L26.2488 10.3438ZM36.9519 15.3594V15.6875C36.9519 16.9167 36.806 18.0573 36.5144 19.1094C36.2331 20.1615 35.8165 21.0781 35.2644 21.8594C34.7123 22.6302 34.0248 23.2344 33.2019 23.6719C32.3894 24.099 31.4519 24.3125 30.3894 24.3125C29.3581 24.3125 28.4623 24.1042 27.7019 23.6875C26.9415 23.2708 26.3008 22.6875 25.78 21.9375C25.2696 21.1771 24.8581 20.2969 24.5456 19.2969C24.2331 18.2969 23.9935 17.224 23.8269 16.0781V15.2188C23.9935 13.9896 24.2331 12.8646 24.5456 11.8438C24.8581 10.8125 25.2696 9.92188 25.78 9.17188C26.3008 8.41146 26.9363 7.82292 27.6863 7.40625C28.4467 6.98958 29.3373 6.78125 30.3581 6.78125C31.431 6.78125 32.3738 6.98438 33.1863 7.39062C34.0092 7.79688 34.6967 8.38021 35.2488 9.14062C35.8113 9.90104 36.2331 10.8073 36.5144 11.8594C36.806 12.9115 36.9519 14.0781 36.9519 15.3594ZM32.4363 15.6875V15.3594C32.4363 14.6406 32.3738 13.9792 32.2488 13.375C32.1342 12.7604 31.9467 12.224 31.6863 11.7656C31.4363 11.3073 31.1029 10.9531 30.6863 10.7031C30.28 10.4427 29.7852 10.3125 29.2019 10.3125C28.5873 10.3125 28.0613 10.4115 27.6238 10.6094C27.1967 10.8073 26.8477 11.0938 26.5769 11.4688C26.306 11.8438 26.1029 12.2917 25.9675 12.8125C25.8321 13.3333 25.7488 13.9219 25.7175 14.5781V16.75C25.7696 17.5208 25.9154 18.2135 26.155 18.8281C26.3946 19.4323 26.7644 19.9115 27.2644 20.2656C27.7644 20.6198 28.4206 20.7969 29.2331 20.7969C29.8269 20.7969 30.3269 20.6667 30.7331 20.4062C31.1394 20.1354 31.4675 19.7656 31.7175 19.2969C31.9779 18.8281 32.1602 18.2865 32.2644 17.6719C32.379 17.0573 32.4363 16.3958 32.4363 15.6875ZM45.7788 7.09375V24H41.2631V7.09375H45.7788ZM40.9819 2.6875C40.9819 2.03125 41.211 1.48958 41.6694 1.0625C42.1277 0.635417 42.7423 0.421875 43.5131 0.421875C44.2735 0.421875 44.8829 0.635417 45.3413 1.0625C45.81 1.48958 46.0444 2.03125 46.0444 2.6875C46.0444 3.34375 45.81 3.88542 45.3413 4.3125C44.8829 4.73958 44.2735 4.95312 43.5131 4.95312C42.7423 4.95312 42.1277 4.73958 41.6694 4.3125C41.211 3.88542 40.9819 3.34375 40.9819 2.6875ZM57.7619 20.7969C58.314 20.7969 58.8035 20.6927 59.2306 20.4844C59.6577 20.2656 59.991 19.9635 60.2306 19.5781C60.4806 19.1823 60.6108 18.7188 60.6213 18.1875H64.8556C64.8452 19.375 64.5275 20.4323 63.9025 21.3594C63.2775 22.276 62.439 23 61.3869 23.5312C60.3348 24.0521 59.1577 24.3125 57.8556 24.3125C56.5431 24.3125 55.3973 24.0938 54.4181 23.6562C53.4494 23.2188 52.6421 22.6146 51.9963 21.8438C51.3504 21.0625 50.866 20.1562 50.5431 19.125C50.2202 18.0833 50.0588 16.9688 50.0588 15.7812V15.3281C50.0588 14.1302 50.2202 13.0156 50.5431 11.9844C50.866 10.9427 51.3504 10.0365 51.9963 9.26562C52.6421 8.48438 53.4494 7.875 54.4181 7.4375C55.3869 7 56.5223 6.78125 57.8244 6.78125C59.2098 6.78125 60.4233 7.04688 61.465 7.57812C62.5171 8.10938 63.34 8.86979 63.9338 9.85938C64.5379 10.8385 64.8452 12 64.8556 13.3438H60.6213C60.6108 12.7812 60.491 12.2708 60.2619 11.8125C60.0431 11.3542 59.7202 10.9896 59.2931 10.7188C58.8765 10.4375 58.3608 10.2969 57.7463 10.2969C57.09 10.2969 56.5535 10.4375 56.1369 10.7188C55.7202 10.9896 55.3973 11.3646 55.1681 11.8438C54.939 12.3125 54.7775 12.849 54.6838 13.4531C54.6004 14.0469 54.5588 14.6719 54.5588 15.3281V15.7812C54.5588 16.4375 54.6004 17.0677 54.6838 17.6719C54.7671 18.276 54.9233 18.8125 55.1525 19.2812C55.3921 19.75 55.7202 20.1198 56.1369 20.3906C56.5535 20.6615 57.0952 20.7969 57.7619 20.7969ZM76.5263 24.3125C75.2138 24.3125 74.0367 24.1042 72.995 23.6875C71.9533 23.2604 71.0679 22.6719 70.3388 21.9219C69.62 21.1719 69.0679 20.3021 68.6825 19.3125C68.2971 18.3125 68.1044 17.25 68.1044 16.125V15.5C68.1044 14.2188 68.2867 13.0469 68.6513 11.9844C69.0158 10.9219 69.5367 10 70.2138 9.21875C70.9013 8.4375 71.7346 7.83854 72.7138 7.42188C73.6929 6.99479 74.7971 6.78125 76.0263 6.78125C77.2242 6.78125 78.2867 6.97917 79.2138 7.375C80.1408 7.77083 80.9169 8.33333 81.5419 9.0625C82.1773 9.79167 82.6565 10.6667 82.9794 11.6875C83.3023 12.6979 83.4638 13.8229 83.4638 15.0625V16.9375H70.0263V13.9375H79.0419V13.5938C79.0419 12.9688 78.9273 12.4115 78.6981 11.9219C78.4794 11.4219 78.146 11.026 77.6981 10.7344C77.2502 10.4427 76.6773 10.2969 75.9794 10.2969C75.3856 10.2969 74.8752 10.4271 74.4481 10.6875C74.021 10.9479 73.6721 11.3125 73.4013 11.7812C73.1408 12.25 72.9429 12.8021 72.8075 13.4375C72.6825 14.0625 72.62 14.75 72.62 15.5V16.125C72.62 16.8021 72.7138 17.4271 72.9013 18C73.0992 18.5729 73.3752 19.0677 73.7294 19.4844C74.094 19.901 74.5315 20.224 75.0419 20.4531C75.5627 20.6823 76.1513 20.7969 76.8075 20.7969C77.62 20.7969 78.3752 20.6406 79.0731 20.3281C79.7815 20.0052 80.3908 19.5208 80.9013 18.875L83.0888 21.25C82.7346 21.7604 82.2502 22.25 81.6356 22.7188C81.0315 23.1875 80.3023 23.5729 79.4481 23.875C78.594 24.1667 77.62 24.3125 76.5263 24.3125Z" fill="black"/>
                    <path d="M91.4469 1.25L95.7281 9.1875L100.009 1.25H105.369L98.7594 12.5312L105.541 24H100.134L95.7281 15.9062L91.3219 24H85.8844L92.6813 12.5312L86.0563 1.25H91.4469Z" fill="#4E8341"/>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_middle flex--row">
                <p>Home</p>
                <p>About us</p>
                <p>History</p>
                <p>Saved</p>
            </div>
            <div class="nav_end flex--row">
                <p>Naam</p>
                <svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M25.2513 26.625C25.1055 26.6042 24.918 26.6042 24.7513 26.625C21.0846 26.5 18.168 23.5 18.168 19.8125C18.168 16.0416 21.2096 12.9791 25.0013 12.9791C28.7721 12.9791 31.8346 16.0416 31.8346 19.8125C31.8138 23.5 28.918 26.5 25.2513 26.625Z" stroke="#5C5C5C" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M39.0414 40.3752C35.3331 43.7711 30.4164 45.8336 24.9997 45.8336C19.583 45.8336 14.6663 43.7711 10.958 40.3752C11.1663 38.4169 12.4163 36.5002 14.6455 35.0002C20.3538 31.2086 29.6872 31.2086 35.3539 35.0002C37.5831 36.5002 38.8331 38.4169 39.0414 40.3752Z" stroke="#5C5C5C" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    <path d="M24.9998 45.8333C36.5057 45.8333 45.8332 36.5058 45.8332 25C45.8332 13.494 36.5057 4.16663 24.9998 4.16663C13.4939 4.16663 4.1665 13.494 4.1665 25C4.1665 36.5058 13.4939 45.8333 24.9998 45.8333Z" stroke="#5C5C5C" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                </svg>
                    
            </div>
     </div>  
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.nav_bar{
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 20px;
    gap: 539px;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;


}
.nav_logo{
    justify-content: left;
}
.nav_middle{
    gap: 27px;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;

}
.nav_end{
    align-items: center;
    gap: 27px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.navbar_center{
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 1874px;
    gap: 539px;
    width: 95%;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.background{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1000;
}

.flex--column{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex--row{
    display: flex;
}
```

Tried using justify-content/float but couldnt get it to work